# What are key differences between ImpactJS and MelonJS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, game-engine, impactjs

I'm going to write a simple tile-based RPG game in Javascript, with a big, tile-based map. I looked at this [list of JS game engines](http://html5gameengine.com/), and found out that the only reasonable choices for me are [MelonJS](http://melonjs.org/) and [ImpactJS](http://impactjs.com/) (because of the map editor). Now I see that:

- MelonJS is free and open source, ImpactJS is commercial ($99)
- Both seem up-to-date
- Both seem popular
- Both have tile-based map editors (do they differ much from each other?)
- Both draw on canvas
- Both have sound support

Are there any other important differences I might have overlooked?

Do you have any experience with how they handle big maps, made of big tiles?

How do they compare in terms of performance? I'd like to be able to run my game in full screen.

Comment: One has the word "melon" in it, and melons are great?

Answer (score 5):

First, I must say that I am new to game development. I started a few weeks ago with ImpactJS.

**Why I choose this engine:**

- Good support
- Lots of open source games
- Includes a game level editor
- Includes a publishing tool for iOS App Store with native-like performance
- Books with source code
- Well maintained and updated
- Good community

**There are already 2 books:**

- [HTML5 Game development with ImpactJS](http://www.packtpub.com/html5-game-development-with-impactjs/book)
- [Introducing HTML5 Game Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449315178)

I have one of the books (first one) and it really helped me to boost my development. I can say that ImpactJS is really easy to start with. The framework is very well structured, everything makes sense, even for one that is new in game development!

Hope my answer helps you.

**Update**
I have just finished my first game! You can play it here [Apple Quest](http://www.nunooliveira.me/games-lab/apple-quest/)

Comment: Your game link is down! I know it's been several years, but I'd love to see it still!